# Location did not match - Nested Routes Not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I'm trying to use Nested Routes but it gives me following error:

[image: error message]

Here is my routes code. I'm getting error when I try to use nested routes for Manufacturers.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, IndexRoute, Route, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import {
    App,
    Home,
    ManufacturerDetails,
    ManufacturerList,
  } from 'containers';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" name="Home" component={App} >

        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>

        <Route name="Manufacturers" path="Manufacturers" component={ManufacturerList}>
          <Route name="Manufacturer Details" path="/:manufacturer" component={ManufacturerDetails} />
        </Route>

      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think it because the closing route tag `</Route>` for `path="/"` is missing

Comment: Sorry, it was just copy-paste mistake here. Closing Route is there in file.

Comment: oh i see, I didn't dig into detail but according to my experience the two path should place at same level. `path="Manufacturers"` and `path="Manufacturers/:manufacturer"`, i.e. they are sibling.

Comment: Is "/ABB" working for this route?

Comment: Yes, if I put them on same level. It works fine.

Comment: How are they siblings to each other? Aren't their relationship is parent-child?

Comment: I think if you remove the leading `/` in `/:manufacturer` it should work... relative vs absolute thing.

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: put ``path="/Manufacturers" `` in your route path for `ManufacturerList` component

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to simulate your situation, then I get the same error:

[image: 1st attempt]

---

Then I make the modification and it works:

```html
<Route name="Manufacturers" path="Manufacturers" component={ManufacturerList}>
  <Route name="Manufacturer Details" path=":manufacturer" component={ManufacturerDetails}/>
</Route>
```

i.e. removing the leading `/` in `/:manufacturer`. And it works:

[image: 1st solve]

And it should as there is an [official test](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/cbd1a95b2d9a75febb3eb58d2f9d5a513e432540/modules/__tests__/matchRoutes-test.js#L24) specifically for this route pattern matching.

---

Then I realise you are using `hashHistory`, which will insert a hash character in the address bar.
Just be careful **not to let the '#' mess with the route matching** then it should be okay as well. (or use `browserHistory` as the official doc suggest, if possible.)

[image: 2nd solve]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "/" part from the "Manufacturer Details" route.

`<Route name="Manufacturer Details" path=":manufacturer" component={ManufacturerDetails} />`